# Disable Row selection in DataGrid wpf but not RowHeader

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to disable the row selection but, I've put an textbox in RowHeader (to give the possibility to changed it).

I've found this xaml code to disable HitTestVisible :

```
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

This code disable also RowHeader.

How to active only selection for RowHeader ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the selection of the cells using a `CellStyle`:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

Then you could still select the rows using the `RowHeader`.